# how to set multiple data sets in the work folder using a Do loop?

Tags: sas, datastep

I have 100 individual data sets of demographic information with distinct district names created in my work folder in the following format";

```
data exampleofdistrict;
input districtname$ ASIAN BLACK COLORED WHITE;
cards;
        Aberdeen    0.13 69.14  11.2  19.5
;
run;
```

each individual data set like the one above has a district name

What I want is to combine all these individual distrct datasets to into a single comprehensive dataset;

*I have considered using the regular set statment such as;

```
    data districtscompiled;
    set Aberdeen and *99 other districts in the work folder;
    run;
```

However, my question is, is there a better way to do this than typing the name of each individual data set under the set statement? For instance, could I maybe do a loop within the set statement?

Comment: Why did you split them in the first place, bad design? Do you have a naming convention besides the district names? Can you implement one? If not, are all the data sets in the library going to be combined or only a few? if only a few how are they differentiated?

Comment: I can actually implement a naming convention such that each district data set will  also have a district number. Example districtname_1. All the datasets in the library have to be combined since they represent all districts from a single province

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say implement a naming convention, specifically add a prefix to every data set. It could be as simple as _DISTRICTNAME or DIST_Aberdeen, Dist_Banff. Then you can use the short cut notation to set them all at once, using the colon operator or the - data set list option.

```
data combined;
 set dist_: ; *note the colon here!;
run;
```

If you use a numeric list you can do:

```
data want;
 set district1 - district99; *you need to know the number of districts in this method;
run;
```

[Data Set Lists in documentation](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lrcon&docsetTarget=n0oru3akf51pi5n1wco2onzr39oz.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)